# How to fetch an API response in React?

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm trying to fetch the following API response data in ReactJS. I'm not sure how to do it.. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance, I really appreaciate any help or suggestions given.

For my final output, i want to eventually loop the each of the response in the array and display them just like the API response except in a table which represents each shop with address and postal details.

**API Response**

```
[
  {
    title: 'Paragon',
    address: '290 Orchard Road #B1-03 Singapore 238859',
    postal: '238859'
  },
  {
    title: 'BreadTalk IHQ',
    address: '30 Tai Seng Street #01-02 Singapore 534013',
    postal: '534013'
  },
  {
    title: 'City Square Mall',
    address: '180 Kitchener Road #01-10 Singapore 208539',
    postal: '208539'
  }
]
```

**Code (details.js)**

```
class Crawler extends React.Component {

// Create constructor with props
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Create a state that takes in the SEEDURL
    this.state = {
        seedURL: '',
        response: null,
        error: null
    };
}

    // The seed url taken from the input
    const seedURL = this.state;

    // Take the seedURL and send to API using axios
    const url = "/api";

    // Send data using axios
    axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] ='application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    axios.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
    try {
        // Axios takes in the url and SeedURL
        axios
        .post(url, seedURL)
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({response: res, error: null})
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                this.setState({error: err, response: null})
            });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);

render() {
    return(
        // How do i read the response here?
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try consoling response coming from api ? 
I think you'll get in res.data and then you can setState it into response state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook to get the api data on component mount and update the state. The `state` update will render the component with the updated state.

> You cannot add code directly in class body except `class fields`. you should wrap the code inside a method.

**Example:**

```
class Crawler extends React.Component {
  // Create constructor with props
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      seedURL: 'http://localhost:5000',
      response: [],
      error: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  async fetchData() {
    const seedURL = this.state.seedURL;
    const url = "/api";
    axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    axios.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
    try {
      let res = await axios.post(seedURL + url);
      let data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({ response: data, error: null })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      this.setState({ error: error.message, response: [] })
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>title</th>
              <th>address</th>
              <th>postal</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {(this.state.response.length > 0) ? this.state.response.map(item => (
              <tr key={item.title + item.postal}>
                <td>{item.title}</td>
                <td>{item.address}</td>
                <td>{item.postal}</td>
              </tr>
            )) : null}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you check the network tab, what are yo getting the response .

Comment: its localhost:5000/api, i did a console log to my react js file. im currently using express, not sure why console log only appeared in my `express backend` side but not for my `react frontend`

Comment: Oh dear, i did a console log `res.data` im not retrieving anything on my `frontend`. I did a log at my `backend` i seems to be fine though.

Comment: Im not sure how to put it, but its 500 lines of code. In short, i have two `post api` in the backend. The first api works completely fine. But the second api seems to be not sending any data, im using `res.end(JSON.stringify(data));` to send the API response above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209549/discussion-between-sohail-and-scorezel789).

Comment: Hi Sohail! Thanks for the help earlier. Turns out that my backend response did not went through the front end. I did console log and managed to fixed the error. I was passing an empty array all this while (: All i did was i simply check if the array is populated and send the data over the network..

Comment: Shall we continue this over [link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209549/discussion-between-sohail-and-scorezel789)

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
render() {
    return(<React.Fragment>
{this.state.response && this.state.response.map((r, i)=> <div key={i}>
              <div>{r.title}</div>
              <div>{r.address}</div>
              <div>{r.postal}</div>
          </div>)}
</React.Fragment>
);
}
}
```

Comment: I tried the response.map.. but i got the same error earlier. `TypeError: this.state.response.map is not a function`

Comment: log the outpot using console. Response coming has some different structure. Its not an array looks like

Comment: @scorezel789 i faced the same error few days ago, map function works on array object that is why you are getting this error. Check your code, you must be applying map function on wrong json object.

Answer (score 1):

--Try This Code--

```
class Crawler extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // Create a state that takes in the SEEDURL
        this.state = {
            seedURL: '',
            error: null,
            responses: []
        };
    }

    // The seed url taken from the input
    const seedURL = this.state;

    // Take the seedURL and send to API using axios
    const url = "/api";

    // Send data using axios
    axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    axios.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
        try {
    // Axios takes in the url and SeedURL
    axios
        .post(url, seedURL)
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState({ responses: res, error: null })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            this.setState({ error: err, response: null })
        });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(error);
      this.setState({ error: error.message, response: [] })
    }

    render() {
        const { responses } = this.state;
        return (
            <div >
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>title</th>
                            <th>address</th>
                            <th>postal</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {responses.map(response =>
                            <tr key={response.title - response.postal}>
                                <td>{response.title}</td>
                                <td>{response.address}</td>
                                <td>{response.postal}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe your code should work but im not sure why im getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. Did this code worked on your side?

Comment: Please check your json response as below.
axios
        .post(url, seedURL)
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState({ responses: res, error: null })
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            this.setState({ error: err, response: null })
            console.log(err);
        });

Answer (score 1):

To add to the previous responses where you will find how to loop through the data, add a proxy property in your package.json with the location of your server

"proxy":"http://localhost:5000/api"

and then just do all your requests with what goes after the /api.....Eg: to fetch data from http://localhost:5000/api/cats just do the fetch to /cats

Also check in chrome for the network tab and make sure your request is being sent

Comment: Hi Juan! Thanks for highlighting what is needed to be done! I found my error. Turns out that i my response did not went through the front end. I did console log and managed to fixed the error. I was passing an empty array all this while (:

Comment: That's great to hear.....we all make mistakes...sleeping helps xD